# Move very large MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, amazon-ebs

I have a few very large MySql tables on an Amazon Std EBS 1TB Volume (the file-per-table flag is ON and each ibd file is about 150 GB). I need to move all these tables from database db1 to database db2. Alongwith this, I would also like to move the tables out to a different Amazon Volume (which I think is considered a different Partition/File-System, even if the FileSystem type is the same). The reason I am moving to another volume is so I can get another 1TB space.

Things I have tried:

- `RENAME TABLE db1.tbl1` TO `db2.tbl1` does not help because I cannot move it out to a different volume. I cannot mount a Volume at db2 because then it is considered a different file-system and MYSQL fails with an error:

  > "Invalid cross-device link" error 18
- Created a stub `db2.tbl1, stopped mysql, deleted db2's tbl1 and copied over db1's tbl.ibd.` Doesn't work (the db information is buried in the ibd?)

I do not want to try the obvious mysqldump-import OR selectinto-loadfile because each table takes a day and a half to move even with most optimizations (foreign-key checks off etc). If I take indexes out before the import , re-indexing takes long and the overall time taken is still too long.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: create a snapshot of the current volume and make a new volume from the current snapshot and attached the new volume from the current instance...

Answer (score 0):

Usually what I would suggest in this case, is to create an ec2 snapshot of the volume and write that snapshot into your larger volume.

You'll need to resize the partition afterwards.

As a sidenote, if your database is that large, EBS *might* be a major bottleneck. You're better off getting locally attached storage, but unfortunately the process is a bit different.

You might want to use Percona xtrabackup for this:

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/index.html